# Symfony + Vue: Never loading Vue components?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm popping Vue into a Symfony 4 project, and I've followed all the rules I can find. For some reason, I can not get any Vue components to show up - I can't even execute a console.log from my app.js folder.

Here's app.js:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
import App from './components/App'
console.log('testing')
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App },
});
```

Here's webpack.config:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
```

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

```
/*
 * ENTRY CONFIG
 *
 * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
 * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
 *
 * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
 * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
 */
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
//.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
//.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

// will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
// but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

/*
 * FEATURE CONFIG
 *
 * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
 * list of features, see:
 * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
 */
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableBuildNotifications()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
// enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

// enables Sass/SCSS support
// .enableSassLoader()
.enableSassLoader(function(options) {}, {
    resolveUrlLoader: false
})

// uncomment if you use TypeScript
//.enableTypeScriptLoader()

// uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
.autoProvidejQuery()
.enableVueLoader()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And here's my template:

```
            {% block content %}
             <div id="app"></div>
            {% endblock %}
```

Like I said, even when console.log directly from app.js it doesn't do anything in the console. I'm certain that the build is getting the app.js file, as in my sources I see app.####.js being loaded (hashed version) and it contains the code I've written.

Comment: Are you including the file inside the template? Using: `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}`

Comment: @CarlosFrias I was linking to the file directly, doing it your way worked!

Comment: I added the answer, so that other people with the same issue can find it easier, mark it as the right answer if it helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you include `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}`, in your template.

Comment: As a general solution it makes sense to add this to the base twig template.